# Upload both conda and pypi packages with the same name on Anaconda cloud

Tags: python, anaconda, pypi

I have a python library that I have packaged as a conda and pypi packages:

- mylibrary-1.0.0-py_0.tar.bz2 (conda)
- mylibrary-1.0.0.tar.gz (pypi)

I want to upload these to [anaconda cloud](https://anaconda.org/).

I have managed yo upload my conda package on my personal channel with:

```
anaconda upload mylibrary-1.0.0-py_0.tar.bz2
```

but when I try to upload the Pypi package I have the following error:

```
anaconda upload mylibrary-1.0.0.tar.gz
```

```
Using Anaconda API: https://api.anaconda.org
Using "myusername" as upload username
Processing 'upload mylibrary-1.0.0.tar.gz'
Detecting file type...
File type is "pypi"
Extracting python package attributes for upload
Creating package "mylibrary"
[ERROR] You already have a conda package named 'mylibrary'. Use a different name for this python package.
```

Is there an option to upload them both under the same name so I can install it with either pip or conda ? The only solution I see is to package my Pypi file under a different name which will be confusing for the users.

Comment: Why not upload the sdist to PyPI instead of Anaconda cloud?

Comment: I would like all my artifacts to be hosted at the same place, it's easier to manage. Also I want to have some private packages (which is an Anaconda cloud feature it seems) so I want only one way for users to authenticate for both pypi and conda.

Comment: Yeah, that's a pretty good reason. Sorry I can't help :-)